# Visual Studio not recognizing Color Resource

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am using Mono for Android in Visual Studio 2010.

Resources/Values/Colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_margin="10dp">
 <TextView
    android:text="High Priority Calls"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/urgentCalls"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Build Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@color/red').

I've stared at this for a while now and I just don't see my mistake.

Comment: This is just a guess (hence the comment and not an answer) but your resources file defines `Red` but you're trying to access it as `red` (lower case).  I know in standard Android development case is incredibly important when it comes to resources, etc.

Comment: also, update your xml file name as colors.xml instead of Colors.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your Colors.xml file to use lowercase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```